# Are there a solutions for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha f}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha} = xe^x$?

Tags: fractional-calculus, fractional-differential-equations

Are there solutions for the fractional differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha f}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha} = xe^x$$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$?
I have been using the Caputo definition
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha f}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_0^x \frac{f'(x')}{(x-x')^\alpha}  \mathrm{d} x' $$
but I'm interested in solutions also with other definitions.

With integer order derivatives $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^n f}{\mathrm{d}x^n} = xe^x$$ the solution is $f = (x-n)e^x$, so I guessed that for fractional order the solution might be $f \propto (x-\alpha)e^x$. However, plugging this into the Caputo definition doesn't really work, as one ends up with a lower incomplete Gamma function $\gamma$. I now realize that this is due to the exponential function having the property $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha e^x}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha} \propto e^x \gamma(\alpha, x) \neq e^x .$$

Is there a way to obtain a solution or does this property of the exponentials mean that there is no solution?

Answer (score -1):

For the Caputo derivative using Taylor series, because $\alpha \in (0,1)$ we can swap the integral and sum and we can say

$$D^\alpha (xe^x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n!\cdot\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\int_0^x\frac{(x-x')^n}{{x'}^\alpha}dx' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{\Gamma(n+2-\alpha)}x^{n+1-\alpha}$$

by dominated convergence.

For other fractional derivatives like the Riemann-Liouville variant and its equivalents, one should be able to use Feynman's trick instead $xe^x = \partial_a(e^{ax})|_{a=1}$ to evaluate those integrals.

Comment: You have computed the Caputo derivative of $x e^x$ but I don't see what is has to do with the solution of the fractional differential equation? Based on what you calculated $f=xe^x$ clearly isn't a solution, unless I'm somehow misunderstanding you.

Comment: I don't think the answer is appropriate. It answers the question (how to solve the equation or what the solution is). Also, the answer doesn't add any useful information to the question. In addition, Euler has already shown that it makes a difference whether we take the fractional derivative of the series expansion of a function or the function itself. (my opinion)